# Operations on complex numbers in vertex shader

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, shader, vertex-shader

I am developing a hyperbolic graph for visualizing trees with a large amount of nodes. That's why I am using WebGL, and the ThreeJS library, in order to enhance performance. You can check what I have developed until now here: http://hyperbrowser.herokuapp.com/. The idea is to be able to interact with the graph: clicking a node centers the graph in this node, and dragging and dropping the mouse moves the graph around.

I have been able to display up to 100.000 nodes. But when you drag and drop with such a big amount of nodes, performance drops down. I think that is because now I am doing all the operations with JavaScript itself, and then update the vertices position of my THREE.PointCloud.

After making some research I came up with the idea of performing the operations in the Vertex Shader, directly to the vertices itself. And passing the parameters for the specific transformations in either uniforms or attributes. I think this seems viable, thus I want to ask:

- Whether this is the proper approach or not
- <del>And in case it is, since the transformations I am applying are functions with complex numbers, is there a way to perform this operations in the shaders itself?</del>
  The way is just making the math transformations: https://github.com/julesb/glsl-util

All the code is in https://github.com/vabada/hyperBrowser/ in case you want to see how I am performing any specific operations. Of course any tips, ideas and advice are more than welcome.

Comment: I have not looked at how you constructed your graph but it seems to me that you are only displaying <1000 entities on the screen at the same time? If so its unlikely that drawing is the bottleneck. If you have an appropriate data structure that can encapsulate all data contained in the graph and only pull out the relevant entities you need to draw then that should be enough. Unless your question is that you want to draw 100,000 entities at the same time. But how will that fit in screen?

Comment: The random graph displayed in heroku is, as you say in the order of 100s of nodes. But to generate it, some variables may be modified (like depth, and number of children per node) so that the number of total nodes varies. I made some trials modidying these variables, and it was in the 100k order of magnitude when performance drop way under 60 fps. The idea is to make some clusterization afterwards, so that the graph still remains readable by humans, but thus I would have to calculate the transformation for every node after every movement. That's why I thought in make calculations in the shader

Comment: I think I'm on the way to solve the problem. I am already using the shader material, and now trying to pass the transformation via a uniform. For the complex operations, I saw [here](http://harrisonclarke.wordpress.com/2010/02/07/fractals-on-the-gpu-glsl/) something like this, basically perform the operations in cartesian coordinates:

   vec2 c_mult(vec2 a, vec2 b) {
     return vec2(a.x * b.x - a.y * b.y,
              (a.x+a.y)*(b.x+b.y) - a.x*b.x - a.y*b.y);
   }

Comment: @dabad 1. First, you have 226 draw calls. Google `THREE.LinePieces` and draw a single line. See if that helps. 2. You are instantiating a new `Raycaster` with each mouse move. Create one and reuse it. 3. Make sure you think about how you would do picking if the vertex shader modified the positions.

Comment: Thank you very much @WestLangley That was really helpful. I now define only once the Raycaster, and use the LinePieces. That made me improve a lot the performance. However I would like to try if performing the operations in the shader would smooth the transitions (if you check the example now, with about 100k nodes, it renders good, but decreases a bit when dragging the mouse: http://hyperbrowser.herokuapp.com/hyperbrowser.html?graph=random&depth=12 You can also increase the depth (&depth=12) to render more nodes).
I am not sure I understand your 3rd idea, what do you mean by picking?

Comment: Now it is 3 draw calls. Much better. Picking means selecting items with the mouse.

Comment: Ok. I think I understand you. The problem is that after modifying the points within the shaders, there is no way in javascript to know where the points are right? Since from the vertex shader, next step is the fragment shader and then the screen. So no raycasting?
If it's like that, that would be a problem, since I would like to be able to click every node to display information. So that would be the final solution.
However, I'm going to try to do the transformations in the vertex shader, I'm just loving ThreeJS.
Thank you very much, you were really hepful!

Comment: If you modify the positions in the vertex shader, you can try [GPU picking](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes_gpu.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, I've managed to develop the same solution performing all the operations in the vertex shader. Performance rates are similar, so I'll probably go back to performing the operations with JavaScript. However, it was fun to experiment with shaders, so here is the code for the vertex shader, in case it helps someone.

So, first of all the implemented functions to work with complex numbers (thanks to [julesb](https://github.com/julesb/glsl-util)):

```
Define complex operations
#define product(a, b) vec2(a.x*b.x-a.y*b.y, a.x*b.y+a.y*b.x)
#define conjugate(a) vec2(a.x,-a.y)
#define divide(a, b) vec2(((a.x*b.x+a.y*b.y)/(b.x*b.x+b.y*b.y)),((a.y*b.x-a.x*b.y)/(b.x*b.x+b.y*b.y)))
```

And then the performed transformation in the vertex shader:

```
uniform vec2 t;

void main(){

  vec2 z = vec2(position.x,position.y);
  vec2 newPos = divide((z+t),(vec2(1.0,0) + product((conjugate(t)),z)));
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(newPos, 0, 1.0);

}
```

Comment: Writing complex operations using non-scientific libraries is always tedious.